# ionic 3 navigation transition with push other pages

Tags: animation, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to make animation transition in my ionic 3 app when navigate to page.
I'm using this documentation
 [image]

I declared in my app.module.ts

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
      PageTransition: 'wp-transition'
    }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

then when I navigate to page I wrote this

```
   NavigateToPage(pageName: string){
     let opts = { animate: true, animation: "wp-transition",direction:'forward', duration: 2500}
   pageName === 'TabsPage'? this.navCtrl.setRoot(pageName,opts) : this.navCtrl.push(pageName,opts);
  }

}
```

but I don't see any transition, it looks the same as before.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work(a `push()`) in one of my project by doing this: 
 `this.navCtrl.push(pageName,{/*here stay navParams - but for this example is empty, but still need to use {}*/},opts);`

So without the comment: `this.navCtrl.push(pageName,{},opts);`